# Pandas DataFrame Count Elements Per Category

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Consider the following Pandas dataframe that shows the number of cars sold from different makes and model years:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Y17': [ 1,       2,       1,     1,       0,       0,     1,       2,       2,     0],
                   'Y18': [ 0,       0,       1,     1,       1,       0,     0,       0,       0,     1],
                   'Make': ['Ford',  'Jeep',  'BMW', 'BMW',   'Mazda', 'Jeep', 'Chevy', 'BMW',  'Mazda','Ford']})

Make    Y17 Y18
Ford    1   0
Jeep    2   0
BMW     1   1
BMW     1   1
Mazda   0   1
Jeep    0   0
Chevy   1   0
BMW     2   0
Mazda   2   0
Ford    0   1
```

Every row belongs to the sales of a specific shop (not recorded).

I'd like to pivot this dataframe to get the number of entries such that index is "make" and column is the combination of "year" and "number of sales (multilevel columns are fine). The output should be something like this:

```
           Y17            Y18
        0   1   2      0   1   2
Make            
BMW     0   2   1      1   2   0
Chevy   0   1   0      1   0   0
Ford    1   1   0      1   1   0
Jeep    1   0   1      2   0   0
Mazda   1   0   1      1   1   0
```

Comment: The code to reproduce and the input is different?

Comment: Oops, fixed. Sorry!

Comment: Does `df.melt(['Make', 'Count']).pivot_table(index='Make', columns=['variable', 'Count'], values='value', fill_value=0)` work for you?

Comment: What's `Count`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that in. "Count" is created as `df['Count'] = df.groupby('Make').cumcount()`

Comment: I tried but the counts seem off?!

Answer (score 2):

`melt` then `crosstab`

```
s=df.melt('Make')
pd.crosstab(s.Make,[s.variable,s.value]).stack().fillna(0).unstack()
variable Y17        Y18          
value      0  1  2    0    1    2
Make                             
BMW        0  2  1  1.0  2.0  0.0
Chevy      0  1  0  1.0  0.0  0.0
Ford       1  1  0  1.0  1.0  0.0
Jeep       1  0  1  2.0  0.0  0.0
Mazda      1  0  1  1.0  1.0  0.0
```

Comment: Great, can you explain the steps so I learn how it's done for the next time?

Comment: @Ali first melt you df, then you just need to count the make with values and year, this is more like a pivot count, just your columns have two levels